# I spilled water on my keyboard and now some keys don't work

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I spilled water on my keyboard and some keys didn't work.

Then I replaced the keyboard with a new one and the new keyboard typed more than one letter per one click! I bought a new one and some of the keys didn't work, so I bought another one and the same keys don't work.

I don't know if something happened to the computer or what.

I have tried restoring my Windows and booting in safe mode.

Comment: Was this a laptop keyboard or a stand-alone keyboard?

Comment: stand alone keyboard for my pc

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT via USB , yes I've tried another USB input. nothing happened

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Please always include versions of operating systems and software when you ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have never personally encountered such an issue before, and so I can only speculate. If the keyboard itself has been replaced, and the operating system has been reset, then it sounds like it may be something hardware related. To be certain, I would recommend trying a different operating system. There are many Linux live CDs out there which would allow you to temporarily boot up into a different environment to test the keyboard. Try at least one that doesn't require a GUI, or maybe try inside of a boot prompt, to rule out drivers.

If you still have trouble regardless of they keyboard and the OS then it would be time to start checking the hardware. If you are using a keyboard through a non-USB port, try a USB, and vice versa. Hopefully, this should give you enough information to take some action.